# How to mark time interval from input date

Tags: javascript, date

I have a file input and after loading .csv log history I want to compare dates between input and date from each row. This works when I have static date like in dateFromInput variable ("1 January 2022 20:00:00 UTC") but not after passing date from the input. How to change the code to make it work? Any suggestions?

```js
//example log.csv file:
/*
2011-1-21 8:40:45,zzz,aaa
2012-2-22 9:10:21,aaa,xxx
2014-3-22 10:10:22,aaa,zzz
2017-5-22 17:10:23,aaa,ccc
*/
const compareDate = (a, b) => {
  // a = first Input (each column), b = second Input (user's input)
  if (a < b) {
    alert("older date");
    return -1;  
  } // lt 
  else if (a === b) {
    alert("same date");
    return 0;  
  } // eq
  else if (a > b) {
    alert("newer date");
    return 1;  
  } // gt
  else return null;  // error
}
const makeTableFromCSV = csv => {
  let rows = csv.split("\r\n"), table = document.createElement("table"), tr, td, tdList;
  for (let i = 1; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tdList = rows[i].split(",");
    for (let j = 0; j < tdList.length; j++) {
      td = document.createElement("td");
      if (j === 0) { // First column = date
        td.className = "log-table__cell";  
      }
      td.innerHTML = tdList[j];
      tr.appendChild(td);  
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
const clearInput = input => input.value = "";
const formatDate = (data, date) => date = new Date(data);
const convertDateToMiliseconds = date => date.getTime();
const addClassToRow = (row, className) => row.classList.add(className);
const getDateFromColumn = collection => {
  let dateColumns = document.getElementsByClassName(collection);
  const columns = Array.from(dateColumns);
  return columns;
}
const onFileSelected = ev => {
  const selectedFile = ev.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = ev => {
    makeTableFromCSV(ev.target.result);
    if (ev.target) {
      const columns = getDateFromColumn("log-table__cell");
      columns.forEach(column => {
        let dateFromRow = formatDate(column.innerHTML);
        let milisecondsFromRow = convertDateToMiliseconds(dateFromRow);
        //const inputValue = dateYear.value + " " + dateHour.value;        
        //const dateFromInput = new Date("1 January 2022 20:00:00 UTC");

        // ADDED CODE
        var dateInput = document.getElementById("date1");
        var timeInput = document.getElementById("date2");
        var dateTime = dateInput.value + " " + timeInput.value;
        var dateFromInput = new Date(dateTime);
        // ADDED CODE ENDS

        const inputDateToMs = dateFromInput.getTime();
        const compared = compareDate(milisecondsFromRow, inputDateToMs);
        if (compared === -1) {
          addClassToRow(column, "highlighted");
        }
        console.log(compared, milisecondsFromRow, inputDateToMs);
      });
    }
  };
  reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="onFileSelected(event)">
<br>
<input type="date" id="date1">
<input type="time" id="date2">
<button id="check_date">Compare</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help.

**HTML**

```
<input type="date" id="date">
<input type="time" id="time">
<button id="check">Compare</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#check").click(function() {
    var date1 = new Date("2011-1-21 8:40:45"); // date from csv row
    var date2 = new Date($("#date").val() + " " + $("#time").val());

    // the rest of the codes...
  });
});
</script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var dateInput = document.getElementById("date");
var timeInput = document.getElementById("time");
var dateTime = dateInput.value + " " + timeInput.value;
var date1 = new Date("2011-1-21 8:40:45") // date from csv row
var date2 = new Date(dateTime);

// the rest of the codes...
```

**YOUR CODE**

```
const onFileSelected = ev => {
  const selectedFile = ev.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = ev => {
    makeTableFromCSV(ev.target.result);
    if (ev.target) {
      const columns = getDateFromColumn("log-table__cell");
      columns.forEach(column => {
        let dateFromRow = formatDate(column.innerHTML);
        let milisecondsFromRow = convertDateToMiliseconds(dateFromRow);
        //const inputValue = dateYear.value + " " + dateHour.value;        
        //const dateFromInput = new Date("1 January 2022 20:00:00 UTC");

        // ADDED CODE
        var dateInput = document.getElementById("date1");
        var timeInput = document.getElementById("date2");
        var dateTime = dateInput.value + " " + timeInput.value;
        var dateFromInput = new Date(dateTime);
        // ADDED CODE ENDS

        const inputDateToMs = dateFromInput.getTime();
        const compared = compareDate(milisecondsFromRow, inputDateToMs);
        if (compared === -1) {
          addClassToRow(column, "highlighted");
        }
        console.log(compared, milisecondsFromRow, inputDateToMs);
      });
    }
  };
  reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
}
```

Comment: I don't know how this would work. Could you combine your code with mine and post a link to jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: I've added your code and it doesn't work. I think it should get date from input on click. Look at the code above

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: @miqezjo my added code gets date and time from inputs and convert the into Date object. I have no idea why it does not work in your code.

Comment: @miqezjo if it actually solves your problem, mark it as the answer.